# Memory error in stack

Tags: c++, memory, stack

I'm writing a program to solve this problem:

> Stock stored containers with goods of various kinds of N . All
>   containers are written in N stacks . In each stack may be containers
>   with goods of any species ( stack can be initially empty) .
>
> Forklift can take any of the top container pile and put it on top of
>   any stack . You must put all the containers with the product of the
>   first kind in the first stack , the second type - the second stack ,
>   etc.
>
> The program should print the sequence of actions forklift or a message
>   stating that the problem has no solution .
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line of input contains a single positive integer N, does not
>   exceed 500 . The next N lines describe the stack of containers , first
>   recorded by ki - number of containers in the stack , and then ki
>   properties - types of goods in containers in the stack from the bottom
>   up . At the beginning of each stack of not more than 500 containers (
>   containers during transport this restriction can be broken ) . Output
>   data format The program should print the description of the truck
>   action : for each action type two numbers - from which to take the
>   container stacks and stack which put. ( Note that minimize the amount
>   of truck operations is not required. ) If there is no solution , you
>   need to display a single number 0 . If the containers are initially
>   correctly placed into piles , the output does not need anything .

Example:

Input:

```
3
4 1 2 3 2
0
0
```

Output:

```
1 2
1 3
1 2
```

So, I wrote a program. And you can see the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Здесь, короче, стек.
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
Node* push(Node *start, int d){
    Node *a = new Node;
    a -> data = d;
    a -> next = start;
    return a;
}
Node* pop(Node *s, int &d){
    d = (s -> data);
    Node *a = s -> next;
    delete s;
    return a;
}
void move(Node **stack, int from, int to, int save, int *size, int *number){
    int k = 0;
    while(size[to] != number[to]){
        stack[from] = pop(stack[from], k);
        if(k - 1 == to){
            stack[to] = push(stack[to], k);
            size[to]++;
            cout << from + 1 << " " << to + 1 << endl;
        }
        else{
            stack[save] = push(stack[save], k);
            size[save]++;
            cout << from + 1 << " " << save + 1 << endl;
        }
        size[from]--;
    }
    if(save > to){
        while(size[save] != number[save]){
            stack[save] = pop(stack[save], k);
            stack[from] = push(stack[from], k);
            size[save]--;
            size[from]++;
            cout << save + 1 << " " << from + 1 << endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        while(size[save] != 0){
            stack[save] = pop(stack[save], k);
            stack[from] = push(stack[from], k);
            size[save]--;
            size[from]++;
            cout << save + 1 << " " << from + 1 << endl;
        }
    }

}

void to_one(Node **stack, int to, int m, int *size){
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = to + 1; i < m; i++){
        while(size[i] != 0){
            stack[i] = pop(stack[i], k);
            stack[to] = push(stack[i], k);
            size[to]++;
            size[i]--;
            cout << i + 1 << " " << to + 1 << endl;
        }

    }

}

int main(){
    int n = 0;
    int k = 0;
    cin >> n;
    Node **stack = new Node*[n]; // наши полки
    int *size = new int[n]; // количество элементов на каждой полке изначально
    int *number = new int[n]; // количество элементов соответствующего типа
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) number[i] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> size[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < size[i]; j++){
                cin >> k;
                number[k - 1]++;
                stack[i] = push(stack[i], k);
        } // формируем наши полки
    }
    int from = 0;
    int m = n; // вспомогательная переменная количества неотсортированных полок
    //сперва все перенесем в одну полку (первую)
    to_one(stack, from, m, size);
    int save = 1; // вспомогательная
    //Теперь восстановим последнюю стопку, а вспомогательной будет вторая.
    int to = m - 1;
    move(stack, from, to, save, size, number);
    //Теперь наша готовая последняя стопка станет резервной навсегда.
    save = to;
    //А теперь отдельно рассмотрим полки между последней и первой, повторив цикл выше.
    m--;
    for(int i = m; i > from; i--){
        to = i - 1;
        to_one(stack, from, i, size);
        move(stack, from, to, save, size, number);
    }
    delete []number;
    delete []size;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to debug it and this is what I got.
My input was:

```
4
4 1 2 3 4
1 3
3 2 1 4
3 2 1
```

Program crashed after this output:

```
2 1
3 1
3 1
3 1
4 1
4 1
1 2
```

Screenshot:
[image]

I don't know why I get this error. 
Help me please.

Comment: `0xbaadf00d` seems like a suspicious pointer value if you ask me.

Comment: And, this seems suspicious:  `stack[to] = push(stack[i], k);`

Comment: Look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak
`0xBAADF00D ("bad food") is used by Microsoft's LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED) to indicate uninitialised allocated heap memory when the debug heap is used.`

Comment: Was just about to post what olevegard put.  In other terms, it looks like your stack head moved outside of its memory boundaries somehow.

Comment: Now program works fine, but in judge system it doesn't get all tests because time limit exceeded. And I don't know: is it a problem in infinite loop or in bad algorithm?

Comment: @olevegard I remember 0xFEEDFEED also... but it's not in that list :'|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in

```
stack[to] = push(stack[i], k);
```

Should be

```
stack[to] = push(stack[to], k);
```

Thanks to Joe Z.